# What is the domain of $f(x)$?

Tags: limits

> Let $f_n (x) = \sin (x/n)$ for each $x \in \Bbb{R}$ and $n \in \Bbb{N}$
>
> Calculate $f(x) = \lim _{n \rightarrow  \infty} f_n(x)$ and determine the domain of $f(x)$.

I found the limit and it was $0$, but is the domain of $f(x)$ also $0?$

Also, what is the difference between $f(x)$ and $f_n(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

No! Actually the range of $f$ is $\{0\}$.

$\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$ and $\sin$ function is continuous to see your limit function $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$,  so **the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb{R}$**

For your last question ,ask yourself what is the difference between, for example,  $\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n$ and $e$

Comment: Hi, isn't $(1+1/n)^n$ just $e$?

Comment: $e$ is the limit of the sequence $(1+1/n)^n$. so we know what is meant by a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)$ converging to a real number $a$. Fix $a \in \Bbb{R}$ . We then have a **real number** $f_n(a)$ for $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Thus  we obtain a sequence $(f_n(a))$. So $f(x)$ is a poitwise limit of the **sequence of functions** $f_n(x)$, which means the sequence
$(f_n(x))$ of real numbers converges to the real number $f(x) \in \Bbb{R}$.